# Can we increase count of 10 records in inline lookup field in ms 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

I have a lookup attribute we all know the inline lookup field shows 10 records by default can we increase it?

[image]

I checked the metadata but I didn't get anything relevant.
I don't think we can increase it but still you know we don't know everything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so.

I don't have any source for that, I've just never seen or heard of an option to increase that list size.

Comment: Yeah, even I think so. Thanks for your confirmation.

Comment: @Deep, Happy to help, typically on Stack sites, if an answer was helpful you should accept or up vote it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Can this not be done with JS?  I need to show all lookup values rather than 10.